# Use GPS on a device to determine geolocation inside salesforce.com custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, mobile, geolocation

I've been looking for a way to capture the geolocation from a devices (iphone, ipad, etc) GPS and set the location value on a custom object.  Looking to add an interactive google map or something to the object as well that works in conjunction with the captured location.

I'm having trouble finding a good resource that illustrates something like this.  I've seen plenty of resources that use a defined location or address to make the interactive map but I'm looking for a way for the device to set that location on the fly.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting geolocaiton from mobile browser is easy if you are using a browser that supports it. Try below code,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
function GetLocation(location) {
    console.log(location);
}
```

Once you have got location to javascript, you can easily interact with salesforce API using javascript remoting or AJAX API. Try below link for query details,
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/geolocation-field-types-salesforce1-platform.html